# How to update security credentials in Oracle BI

Tags: oracle11g, oraclereports, oracle-bi, oracle-analytics

The issue is i have a catalogue of reports that have security policies assigned to them. Let's say things like 'manager' can access this report, but not this. This goes on throughout the catalogue. I have been told that a large chunk of reports need these security policies updated. The only thing is is seems very tedious going through each any every report and updating access manually.
Is there a quick way of doing this for say 500+ reports, some nested within others?

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line:

runcat.cmd -cmd setItemPermissions

Use this command with -help suffix to get the documentation and then write what you need.